# Journal article suggestion website or application

Tags: publications, journals, reading

I'm finishing up my PhD in mathematics at the moment. I like to read journal articles from a wide range of different disciplines, and I wonder if there's some kind of service that might suggest articles that I like based on ones that I've already been reading.

For example, Google Chrome has a feature called 'Discover' built into it, where it suggests different articles that I might like to read.  This is mostly news articles, which I do read and find interesting. Sometimes it picks up on some journal articles, or for example some science journalism articles which link to papers.

Is there a website or app which works similarly to this, but suggests only journal articles or web pages which are discussing journal articles, covering a wide range of disciplines?

Comment: Google Scholar has a "Recommended articles" feature, but I don't know how useful it is.

Comment: Maybe you could pick a handful of papers you are interested in (say 10-50) and use a service that sends you email notifications whenever those papers are cited? Alternatively, you could set up RSS feeds that pick out papers by keywords of your choosing (for example, arXiv has this feature)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few *paper recommender systems* (a highly active area of research, by the way; see this Google Scholar [search on "paper recommender systems"](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=paper%20recommender%20systems)). They first draw from a corpus of research publications you 'follow', have read or stored; second, they use algorithms to find related papers; and third, they recommend these related papers to you.

To name a few platforms:

- **Google Scholar**: You can 'follow' Google Scholar profiles with the option to get e-mail alerts with publications related to the followed
  profiles' research. This is possibly the widely used approach.
- **ResearchGate**: You can 'follow' ResearchGate profiles, and the RG main site will show you papers related to their publications.
- **Academia.edu**: Same like ResearchGate, but including with the option to get e-mail alerts.
- **Mendeley**: If you use Mendeley, its feature "Mendeley Suggest" sends you (I think weekly?) e-mails to recommend similar papers to
  you as the ones you have stored.
- **Twitter**: Follow journals and 'journal lists' (an aggregation of Twitter profiles of journals, such as [this one on Political
  Science](https://twitter.com/i/lists/1033736443951239168)) on Twitter, and you will see them announcing their newest publications in your Twitter feed.

In addition, there are some platforms that require you to type in a DOI of a paper and that then search for papers that are in a co-citational relationship with the DOIs. Just some examples:

- **CitationGecko**: https://citationgecko.azurewebsites.net/
- **ConnectedPapers**: https://www.connectedpapers.com/
- **CoCites**: https://www.cocites.com/

Comment: This is great thanks for your help